# Copying cells between 2 sheets

Tags: vba, excel, copy

What I'm trying to do is simply copy information from one sheet to another based on the contents of the cell. Basically, if a number from Column A, sheet 1 matches a number in Column A, Sheet 2 I would like it to copy the entire row from Sheet 2 over to sheet 1 with **two cells seperation beside** the row where it matched.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Please let me know if you need anymore clarification.

**PSEUDO**

```
For i = 1 to EndofColumnInSheet1
       if (There is a match with xNumber in sheet 2)
           {
              Copy entire row in Sheet 2 beside matching row in Sheet 1 
           }

       else
            {
                Keep entire row empty.
                AKA Skip this row.
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple loop seems to run fairly quickly.

```
Dim r As Long, cc As Long, cr As Long, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet10")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet11")

With ws1
    For r = 1 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If CBool(Application.CountIf(ws2.Columns(1), .Cells(r, 1).Value)) Then
            cr = Application.Match(.Cells(r, 1).Value, ws2.Columns(1), 0)
            cc = ws2.Cells(cr, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            .Cells(r, 4).Resize(1, cc) = ws2.Cells(cr, 1).Resize(1, cc).Value
        Else
            'do nothing
        End If
    Next r
End With

Set ws2 = Nothing
Set ws1 = Nothing
```

Comment: How do you think I would I go about changing this so it only copies a specific cell value to the original sheet?